# Как получить данные из iframe с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: iframe, javascript

Здравствуйте, уважаемые...<br>
Подскажите пожалуйста новичку в JavaScript, **как получить данные из iframe**?
Имеется такой iframe, в файле **index.html**:

```
<iframe src="test.html" name="contentBlock" id="contentBlock"></iframe>
```

**index.html** в одной директории с файлом **test.html**
то есть я беру информацию не с другого домена, информация должна быть доступна, однако не получается :(

test.html - содержит подобный код:

```
<body>123 123 123</body>
```

Жду от Вас ответов, с очень подробными и главное работающими примерами, чтобы мог копипаснуть и сразу всё работало, а дальше разбираться уже, заранее всем благодарен за старания.

Comment: > Жду от Вас ответов, с очень подробными и главное работающими примерами, чтобы мог **копипаснуть** и сразу всё работало, а дальше разбираться уже, заранее всем благодарен за старания

вам к фрилансерам.

Comment: не будьте так жестоки, просто на работающем примере, куда удобнее разобраться. Ну нет так, нет. Рад тому, чем помогают, только пока не работает код в Хроме :(

Comment: так копипастнуть или пример ? примеров куча.

Comment: можно пример, главное, чтобы в хроме работало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.frames.contentBlock.document.body.innerHTML
```

Comment: ничего не выходит к сожалению, у Вас получилось? Скиньте пожалуйста полный пример.

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 </head>
 <body id="c1" name="c1">
  дальше будет ифреейм
  <iframe src="test.html" name="contentBlock" id="contentBlock"></iframe>
  конец ифрейма<p>
  <a href="#" onClick="readFrame()">readFrame</a>
  <script>
   function readFrame() {
   document.write(document.frames.contentBlock.document.body.innerHTML);
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: прошу прощения. window.frames, а не document.frames.  

ЗЫ в опере работает и document.frames тоже.

Comment: хм. и правда в опере работает, а вот в хроме пишет две такие ошибки:
        Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. index2.html:12
readFrame index2.html:12
onclick index2.html:9
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined index2.html:12
readFrame index2.html:12
onclick

Comment: да, есть такая тема, что файлы просто с диска открываемые попадают под отдельную политику безопасности. на сервере все нормально будет работать.

Comment: Вот [обсуждение](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950598/using-iframe-with-local-files-in-chrome) на SO (второй ответ). Но так ли важно открывать файлы напрямую? Вам все равно в будущем понадобится по мере обучения сервер, поставьте денвер (или что там нынче модно?) и тестируйте с сервером. ajax опять же без сервера работать не будет...

Comment: а с диска, как в хроме сделать, чтобы работало нормально? в опере всё без проблем.

Comment: форкнуть хромиум и поправить в исходниках. это не баг, а фича.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert( $("#contentBlock").contents().find("body").html() );
```

Comment: что-то не работает, это не jQuery ли случаем?
Можно полный код, как правильно написать? :)